# Calculating the expected payoff in a 2-finger morra game

Tags: probability, game-theory

> Person A and Person B are playing a two-finger morra game, where they
>   each show either one finger or two fingers, at the same time.
>
> If the sum of the fingers is even, person A gets the product of the
>   two fingers. If the sum of the fingers is odd, person B gets the
>   product of the two fingers.
>
> What's the expected payoff for Person A?

Here are the possibilities:

```
Person A plays 1, person B plays 1 ==> Person A wins 1 dollar
Person A plays 2, person B plays 1 ==> Person B wins 2 dollars
Person A plays 1, person B plays 2 ==> Person B wins 2 dollars
Person A plays 2, person B plays 2 ==> Person A wins 4 dollars
```

Lets assume that the probability that Person A chooses 1 is $p$, and lets assume that Person B knows $p$ and can choose his strategy based on this information.

How would I find the expected payoff for A?

I want to say that the expected payoff for A is:
$p - 2(1-p) - 2p + 4(1-p)$

But I don't know if this is correct

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I would expect the payoff of $A$ to be $0$ if $p=0$ or $1$, since $B$ can always win.

Comment: Your proposed expected payoff for A simplifies to $-3p+2$.  This suggests that A should take $p=0$ (which means that A would always show two fingers.  According to your formula this gives A an expected payoff of $2$.  But if A always shows two fingers, B will always show one finger, and hence B will always win $2$.  (That is, A's expected payoff is $-2$.)

Answer (score 0):

You can model this as the zero-sum game with payoff matrix
$$G = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & -2 \\
- 2 & 4
\end{array}
\right]$$
The unique maximin (or equilibrium) strategies are $p=P(A \mbox{ plays } 1) = 2/3$ and $q=P(B \mbox{ plays } 1) = 2/3$. The value of the game is $0$.